# I am unable to get AJAx Call using Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have below code, i am unable to see output but when i see in firebug i can see output...but not in html table.

```
 [View]
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/general.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="submit" name="getdata" id="getdata" value="Submit"/>

  <div id="result_table">

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Controller

```
  class Ajax1 extends CI_Controller {
      private $limit = 30;
      private $offset = 4;
  function __construct()
      {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->model('User_model','',TRUE);
          $this->load->model('Person_model','',TRUE);

      }
  public function index()
  {
      $this->load->view('ajax1');
  }
  public function get_all_users() {
      $this->output->set_content_type('text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
      $query = $this->Person_model->get_paged_list(10, 0)->result();
      $text = "Hi,testing";
          $this->load->view('ajax1');
      echo json_encode($query);

  }
  }
  ?>
```

AJax
            // JavaScript Document

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#getdata').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/wizaptech/index.php/ajax1/get_all_users",
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(output_string){
                        $("#result_table").append(output_string);
                    } // End of success function of ajax form
                }); // End of ajax call
         });
    });
```

So can any one give me idea what i am missing plz.....

I have included ajax code

Comment: Where are you telling your form that it's an ajax request? What javascript do you use?

Comment: hi  use this $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($query));

Comment: I have mention ajax code, plz check if i have missed something

Comment: Farooq, where should i add your code.....can you give me idea plz

Answer (score 0):

hi right now your output going back as javascript, you have set your content type javascript one more thing your are loading view also in your method which is not required

```
public function get_all_users() {
      $query = $this->Person_model->get_paged_list(10, 0)->result();
      $text = "Hi,testing";
      $this->output ->set_content_type('application/json') 
      ->set_output(json_encode($query));
  }
```